# How can I uniquely identify an IMAP message after copying it?

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I want to move an IMAP message from INBOX to INBOX/Archive using python's [`imapclient`](http://imapclient.freshfoo.com/) library, which I'm doing basically like this:

```
def archive_message(imap, message_id):
    imap.copy([message_id], getOptions().imap_archive_folder)
    imap.delete_messages([message_id])
```

However, this loses my reference to the message. What I want to do is to store an identifier for the message that will allow me to look up the message later, using something like this:

```
def retrieve_message(imap, MYSTICAL_STORED_ID):
    imap.select_folder(getOptions().imap_archive_folder)
    return imap.fetch([MYSTICAL_STORED_ID], parts=["RFC822"])
```

What ID should I / can I use for this, and how would I do the lookup part of this?

Comment: In most cases, the server will support the `UIDPLUS` extension and thus the new UID of the copy in the remote folder is part of the return value from your call to `imap.copy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value in the `Message-Id` header is supposed to be unique per email message.

Comment: So, assuming I've SELECTed a folder, this is sufficient to identify the message for retrieval?

Comment: You *may* need to scan the folder for the appropriate message and get its index; I don't actually know IMAP all that well.

Comment: The problem is that you can have multiple copies of a single message in a folder. (See that **imap.copy**? You don't have to follow it with an **imap.delete_messages**...)

Comment: Sure, but that's just multiple instances of the same message, and the `Message-Id` can be used to weed them out.